# How to solve the following ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following ode [(orig. form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U8bA.png) is difficult for me to be solved, I hope anyone can help me 
$$
\ddot x+x = \frac58a^5\cos(3(t+b))\sin(2(t+b))
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use $$\sin(A)\cos(B)=\frac12[\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)]$$ to bring the right side into a more usual format.

Comment: You should recognize the standard oscillator, the solution of the homogeneous equation is $A\cos t+B\sin t$. And yes, that means that there is resonance.

Comment: @RoonAnnHo Could you please show some effort toward finding the solution yourself?

Comment: Yeah, and I have solved the general solution: $$A\sin t+B \cos t$$

Comment: Yeah, and I have solved the solution of the homogeneous equation $$A\sin t+B \cos t$$, but I don't know how to solve the solution of the nonhomogeneous equation, especially the particular form of the solution to the nonhomogeneous equation

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you don't want to use @LutzL's excellent suggestion, you can try the ansatz

$$A\cos(3t)\cos(2t)+B\cos(3t)\sin(2t)+C\sin(3t)\cos(2t)+D\sin(3t)\sin(2t)$$

(dropping the unessential constants).

Plug in the LHS and identify the coefficients. Tedious but workable.

---

A little of thinking shows yo that the terms $\cos\cos$ and $\sin\sin$ are unnecessary.